# Replace if elif block in python

Tags: python, conditional-statements

It turned out that this conditional block keeps on repeating itself in my code. Any other way to make my life easier? Of course, the body to be executed for a condition differs.

```
if self.datatype == "string":
    t = "z"
elif self.datatype == "double":
    t = "d"
elif self.datatype == "number":
    t = "i"
elif self.datatype == "blob":
    t = "z"
else:
    raise EntParEx("Unknown datatype" + self.datatype)
```

......more code using the same conditional

```
def emit_cpp_def(self):
    s = ""
    e = ""
    if self.datatype == "string":
        s += "static const int " + self.lenvar + " = " + self.length + ";"
        s += "\nchar"
        e += "[" + self.lenvar + " + 2" + "]"
    elif self.datatype == "double":
        s += "double"
    elif self.datatype == "number":
        s += "int"
    elif self.datatype == "blob":
        s += "char*"
    else:
        raise EntParEx("Unknown datatype" + self.datatype)

    s += " " + self.cpp_membername;
    s += e
    s += ";"
    return s;

def emit_cursor_def_code(self):
    if self.datatype == "blob":
        return ""

    ret = "nvl(" + self.db_fieldname + ", "
    #TODO: Add default value loading!
    if self.datatype == "string":
        ret += "\' \'"
    elif self.datatype == "double":
        ret += "-1.0"
    elif self.datatype == "number":
        ret += "-1"
    else:
        raise EntParEx("Unknown datatype" + self.datatype)
    ret += "), "
    return ret
```

EDIT: 
I think what I need is something like running a specific function for each type. Unfortunately I'm not that versed in python. Can that be done? i.e.

```
switch_datatype(function_string(), function_integer(), ...etc)
```

Is this worse?

Comment: Is this how you indented your code? Because if it is, it's incorrect.

Comment: Probably not. Markdown and its four spaces for code blocks gets annoying.

Comment: The dictionary based answers work just as well if you put functions in the dictionary and then call them: `datatypes[self.datatype]()`. For some situations you might even want to mix strings and functions in the same dictionary, pull out the value and only call it if it needs it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If it’s the exact same conditional, stick it in a method and call it where you need it. Otherwise, define the dictionaries somewhere and use whichever you need.

```
datatypes = {'string': 'z', 'double': 'd', 'number': 'i', 'blob': 'z'}
t = datatypes[self.datatype]
```

You may catch the KeyError and raise a domain exception.

Comment: I like this answer, but I added my own to demonstrate that you can if you want customise the exception in just a single place.

Answer (score 4):

Building on @jleedev's answer, it you really are doing this a lot, *and* if you want a custom exception:

```
class EntParEx(KeyError): pass
class DataMapping(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        raise EntParEx("unknown datatype {}".format(key))


>>> datatypes = DataMapping(string='z', double='d', number='i', blob='z')
>>> datatypes['string']
'z'
>>> datatypes['other']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    datatypes['other']
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 3, in __missing__
    raise EntParEx("unknown datatype {}".format(key))
EntParEx: 'unknown datatype other'
```

Edit to add code for the extended example:

```
>>> datatypes = DataMapping(string='static const int {lenvar} = {length};\nchar {cpp_membername}[{lenvar}+2];',
        double='double {cpp_membername};',
        number='int {cpp_membername};',
        blob='char* {cpp_membername};')
>>> inst = C()
>>> inst.lenvar = 'a'
>>> inst.length = 5
>>> inst.cpp_membername='member'
>>> datatypes['number'].format(**vars(inst))
'int member;'
>>> datatypes['string'].format(**vars(inst))
'static const int a = 5;\nchar member[a+2];'
```

Comment: I like this approach, but since we're emulating a built-in type (dict) it might be better to base our custom exception from KeyError, just for consistency.

Comment: @efotinis, good point, I've updated my answer to do that. Interestingly it changes the stack backtrace slightly: there are now single quotes round the exception message.

Comment: the single quotes are there because KeyError's `__init__` expects just the key in question as its argument and you're implicitly passing it the whole message string instead. Personally, I'd simply use 'raise EntParEx(key)' and perhaps change the exception name to something more descriptive (e.g. ParserDatatypeError).

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something more dynamic.

```
type(self.datatype).__name__
```

Returns "str", "float", "int", etc. You could take the first character of that.